# How to build a react native project with cocoapods and workspace?

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, xcodebuild

Before I install Pods and add a workspace to my react native project I build my project successfully using this command:

```
xcodebuild -scheme [SchemeName] archive -archivePath ./build/[AppName].xcarchive -allowProvisioningUpdates
```

I installed [RN Firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/ios) using CocoaPods and it need a xcworkspace to manage packages. According this I added the workspace option to allow the xcodebuild to find Pods:

```
-workspace [AppName].xcworkspace
```

After adding this option, the build failed because it don't find main.jsbundle.

```
Loading dependency graph, done.

SHA-1 for file /Users/nicolas/development/git/availpro.mobile/index.js is not computed

ReferenceError: SHA-1 for file /Users/nicolas/development/git/availpro.mobile/index.js is not computed
    at DependencyGraph.getSha1 (/Users/nicolas/development/git/availpro.mobile/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:201:13)
    at /Users/nicolas/development/git/availpro.mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:164:26
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/nicolas/development/git/availpro.mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:31:30)
    at /Users/nicolas/development/git/availpro.mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:50:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/nicolas/development/git/availpro.mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:28:12
    at Transformer.transformFile (/Users/nicolas/development/git/availpro.mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:188:7)
    at /Users/nicolas/development/git/availpro.mobile/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:78:34
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)

+ [[ false != true ]]
+ [[ ! -f /Users/nicolas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AvailproMobile-gewuoxculvshvhehwwobcbkhdzba/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/AvailproMobile-staging/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/AvailproMobile.app/main.jsbundle ]]
+ echo 'error: File /Users/nicolas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AvailproMobile-gewuoxculvshvhehwwobcbkhdzba/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/AvailproMobile-staging/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/AvailproMobile.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with'
error: File /Users/nicolas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AvailproMobile-gewuoxculvshvhehwwobcbkhdzba/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/AvailproMobile-staging/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/AvailproMobile.app/main.jsbundle does not exist. This must be a bug with
+ echo 'React Native, please report it here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues'
React Native, please report it here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues
+ exit 2
```

To quick fix the issue I generate the main.jsbundle manually before the xcodebuild:

```
react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/[AppName]/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest='./ios'
```

This fix seems to me a hack than a real solution.

Anyone can tell me why building the project using a .xcworkspace don't generate the main.jsbundle while building a .xcodeproj generate it ?

Thanks!